OpenCV and Libtorch conflict
Ubuntu 24 system; CLion IDE. When trying to run code using OpenCV and Libtorch, the following errors occur:
main.cpp:34:(.text+0xa28): undefined reference to `cv::putText(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, std::string const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, double, cv::Scalar_<double>, int, int, bool)'

main.cpp:45:(.text+0xbb1): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(std::string const&, int)'

main.cpp:64:(.text+0xe04): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'

The interesting thing is that the application that depends exclusively on OpenCV (and uses the above functions) works without problems. The application that uses exclusively Libtorch also runs without problems. This happens in the same project, the code (obviously) and CMake lists are different.
An example of CMake with which a pure OpenCV application works:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(libtorch)

find_package (OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(libtorch main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(libtorch ${OpenCV_LIBS})

An example of CMake with which a pure Libtorch application works:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(libtorch)

find_package(Torch REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS}")

add_executable(libtorch main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(libtorch "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")
set_property(TARGET libtorch PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)

CMake example with which errors appear in a mixed application:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(libtorch)

find_package (OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS}")

add_executable(libtorch main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(libtorch ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(libtorch "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")
set_property(TARGET libtorch PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)

This happens in the same project. In CLion, the flag is -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/include/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch/
Here is the code that doesn't work:
#include <torch/script.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

const int INPUT_WIDTH = 320;
const int INPUT_HEIGHT = 320;
const float SCORE_THRESHOLD = 0.5;
const float NMS_THRESHOLD = 0.5;
const int PERSON_CLASS_ID = 1;
const std::string VIDEO_PATH = "path";
const std::string MODEL_PATH = "ssdlite320_mobilenet_v3_large.pt";

torch::Tensor preprocess_image(cv::Mat& image) {
    cv::Mat resized;
    resize(image, resized, cv::Size(INPUT_WIDTH, INPUT_HEIGHT));
    cvtColor(resized, resized, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);

    torch::Tensor tensor_image = torch::from_blob(resized.data, {1, INPUT_HEIGHT, INPUT_WIDTH, 3}, torch::kByte);
    tensor_image = tensor_image.permute({0, 3, 1, 2});
    tensor_image = tensor_image.toType(torch::kFloat);
    tensor_image = tensor_image.div(255);
    return tensor_image;
}

void draw_predictions(cv::Mat& image, const torch::Tensor& predictions) {
    auto pred_accessor = predictions.accessor<float, 2>();
    for (int i = 0; i < predictions.size(0); ++i) {
        if (pred_accessor[i][5] == PERSON_CLASS_ID && pred_accessor[i][4] > SCORE_THRESHOLD) {
            int x1 = static_cast<int>(pred_accessor[i][0] * image.cols);
            int y1 = static_cast<int>(pred_accessor[i][1] * image.rows);
            int x2 = static_cast<int>(pred_accessor[i][2] * image.cols);
            int y2 = static_cast<int>(pred_accessor[i][3] * image.rows);
            rectangle(image, cv::Point(x1, y1), cv::Point(x2, y2), cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
            putText(image, "Person", cv::Point(x1, y1 - 10),
                        cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    torch::jit::script::Module model = torch::jit::load(MODEL_PATH);
    model.eval();

    cv::VideoCapture cap(VIDEO_PATH);
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening video file" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cv::Mat frame;
    while (cap.read(frame)) {

        torch::Tensor input_tensor = preprocess_image(frame);

        std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs;
        inputs.push_back(input_tensor);
        torch::Tensor output = model.forward(inputs).toTensor();

        torch::Tensor predictions = output.squeeze().detach();

        draw_predictions(frame, predictions);

        imshow("Person Detection", frame);

        if (cv::waitKey(1) == 27) break;

    }

    cap.release();
    cv::destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}

And here is OpenCV-only code that does work:
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

const std::string videoPath = "path";

void preprocessFrame(cv::Mat& frame) {
    cv::resize(frame, frame, cv::Size(240, 160));
}

void applyBackgroundSubtraction(cv::Mat& frame, cv::Ptr<cv::BackgroundSubtractor>& bgSubtractor, cv::Mat& fgMask) {
    bgSubtractor->apply(frame, fgMask);
}

void applyNoiseReduction(cv::Mat& fgMask) {
    cv::GaussianBlur(fgMask, fgMask, cv::Size(15, 15), 0);

    cv::erode(fgMask, fgMask, cv::Mat(), cv::Point(-1, -1), 2);
    cv::dilate(fgMask, fgMask, cv::Mat(), cv::Point(-1, -1), 2);
}

int main() {
    cv::VideoCapture cap(videoPath);
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Could not open the video file!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cv::Ptr<cv::BackgroundSubtractor> bgSubtractor = cv::createBackgroundSubtractorKNN(100, 2000, false);

    cv::Mat frame, fgMask;

    while (cap.read(frame)) {
        if (frame.empty()) break;

        preprocessFrame(frame);
        applyBackgroundSubtraction(frame, bgSubtractor, fgMask);
        applyNoiseReduction(fgMask);
        cv::imshow("Foreground Mask (Noise Reduced)", fgMask);
        if (cv::waitKey(30) == 27) break;
    }

    cap.release();
    cv::destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;
}


Please, post the exact C++ code which you are building and exact error messages. Knowing that very similar project works without Torch is useful, but that doesn't make unnecessary regular debugging details, like code and error message.

I've seen some posts about some incompatibilities of those two libraries (one may have been about the c++ standard setting used to build them). Do some research. And BTW, naming that executable "libtorch" just seems like asking for a name conflict.

@DanMašek If there is problem with C++ standard used to build them, will compiling both from sources help?

@Tsyvarev added code and error messages

Find out how in CLion you could see the exact command line options passed to the compiler. Determine options which are used when you compile main.cpp (e,g, you could add a comment line to that file, so it will force CLion to recompile it). Check, whether compile macro _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI is defined, and to which value. Then repeat for the case when you use only OpenCV (without Torch). If different values for the macro are used, then this could be a problem.
